# hide and show two buttons after clicked on it

Tags: jquery, show-hide, buttonclick

Please give me an example based on my buttons in below **without using onclick function**:

```
<button id="button1">Example 1</button>
<button id="button2" style='display:none;'>Example 2</button>
```

For example:

> Button1 is default, after clicked on it will hide and button2 will be
>   appeared and after click on button2 again will hide and button1 will
>   be appeared.

I need a jQuery for this just with ID, not onclick function.

Is it possible to get ID for buttons for hide and show?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can get the ID with Jquery using $("#button1") and $("#button2") but you need to act in the click function to be abble to show or hide

Comment: The jquery work with event for exmple `onclick`,`onhover`,`onkeypress`, without event must be automate in interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something simple using **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**, also you cant do it without click event handler

```js
var btn = $('#button1,#button2').click(function() { // bind click handler to both button
  $(this).hide(); // hide the clicked button
  btn.not(this).show(); // show the another button which is hidden
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Example 1</button>
<button id="button2" style='display:none;'>Example 2</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, your code is working well here but when I put it in html, it won't work, why ?

Comment: @AlexanderRichard :  add jquery library before your code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` , and put your code within document ready handler  `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here });`

Comment: @AlexanderRichard : glad to help you :)